# What is the difference in meaning when combining two sentences into one?

Tags: grammar

I see the following correction for one of the books I'm reading:

> On page 122, in the first line, the expression "*Let **Fa** be set of all finite subsets of **A**. Define ...*" should be "*Let **Fa** be the set of all finite subsets of **A** and define ...*".

Ignoring the technical detail, I don't see show the meaning of the sentence changes with the correction. So what is the difference here?

Answer (score 1):

It's just a stylistic choice, so that it reads less like a recipe (or other set of instructions). The meaning is the same.